# Change input from analog to digital clock in Google apps

Tags: google, google-calendar, clock

So Google changed their alarm clock and calendar a while ago so that instead of entering exact numbers with a numpad (left image), you have to start searching for the exact spot to touch in a radial clock (right image).

[image: old style]  [image: new style]

Anyone know of a way to get rid of this thing and use a normal numpad to enter hour & minutes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, it's not possible to use a keyboard with this new type of time picker, because it is not a feature of this mode ("clock", right image) of the control. But if the developer of an app showing the time picker uses the classic mode ("spinner", left image) which is still present in newer APIs (21+), you can use the keyboard.

Maybe if you give feedback about this annoyance to Google, they will enable the use of keyboard as an alternative to manually selecting the numbers in the radial clock for newer versions of Android.

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with bloated annoying software, I use [Simple Alarm Clock Free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ar.com.basejuegos.simplealarm) instead. It has a digital entry, much like KitKat. It is not tightly integrated with the clock; but it is lightweight and simple.